# Salesforce mobile app - send detaiils in account on authorization of app

Tags: android, salesforce

I am working on android app which is based on salesforce.

I have created an app within salesforce which provides me consumer key and 
Callback URL.

Then i downloaded salesforce mobile sdk and import it in eclipse and tried sample and it works.

So, when i run an app it asks first time to authorize an app with my account and after click on allow it moves to next page in my android app.

So, my problem is this that when i start this app then i want to send contact details to my salesforce account on click of allow while authorizing app.

Please help me out to solve this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: By the way you can ask your question about salesforce directly at salesforce.stackexchange.com